# Language usage: group theory

Tags: group-theory, terminology, cyclic-groups

Is it perfectly okay to say "In  a  finite  cyclic  group,  two  elements  generate  the  same  subgroup  if  and
only if the elements have the same order" as it contains the word "generate", or how to say it in a much more acceptable way?

Comment: It looks OK to me. What is your specific concern about the use of the word "generate"?

Comment: Thanks! My concern is because "generator" has a specific meaning

Comment: So does "generate": an element **generates** a subgroup if it is a **generator** of the subgroup. This is standard terminology. You are using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's okay.

A generator $g$ of a group $G$ is an element that, potentially with other elements, generate the group $G$; which is to say that all other elements of $G$ are products of the generators.